# Why would my Azure Function not load my environment variables correctly in startup.cs?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, configuration, azure-functions

We have a C# precompiled v4 Azure Function on .NET 6.0 on Windows App Service. We have the following code in Startup.cs:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath, $"local.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);

    builder.Services.AddSingleton(s =>
    {
        var connectionString = config["Azure:CosmosDB:ConnectionString"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)) throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Please specify a valid CosmosDBConnection in the local.settings.json file or your Azure Functions Settings.");

        return new CosmosClientBuilder(connectionString)
           .Build();
    });
    
    // Additional services configuration
}
```

And we have the necessary package references in csproj:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

This works well running locally in VS 2022 and loading from `local.settings.json`, but fails on the null connection string check, throwing the `InvalidOperationException` shown, when deployed to the cloud, despite the environment variable being correctly set:

[image]

What are we missing here?

Comment: I guess, you have to name it as only `ConnectionString` in the Azure Portal Function App Configuration! Could you try it once!

Comment: local.settings.json is only when you are running locally for development. For reading application settings from portal when you deploy, you need to use GetEnvironmentVariable function. Actually this works to get config values from both local file as well as portal config values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#environment-variables

Comment: I'm aware of that concept @JudeFisher. In Azure Function App Portal Configuration, there are two sections called Application Settings and Connection Strings. In which section you've defined the connection string key-value?

Comment: The issue had nothing to do with the connection string name, or which section of config was used. And we should be able to use IConfig with AddEnvironmentVariables and an optional json file - this is a standard dev > production pattern. The fix was something else. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thanks @BarkhaJain - that would have been another solution. We prefer to stick with the pattern of using IConfiguration - we have services that operate in multiple environments, where GetEnvironmentVariable is not always available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for us was to override `ConfigureAppConfiguration` to initialize Config, and (since we need to access it elsewhere in startup) to set it as a variable on the Startup.cs class.

```
    public IConfiguration Config { get; private set; }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(s =>
        {
            var connectionString = Config["Azure:CosmosDB:ConnectionString"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)) throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Please specify a valid CosmosDBConnection in the local.settings.json file or your Azure Functions Settings.");

            return new CosmosClientBuilder(connectionString)
                .Build();
        });

    // Etc.
    }

    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath, $"local.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Config = builder.ConfigurationBuilder.Build();

    }
```

Since `AddSingleton` is passed an action, and that action isn't called until the service is required, then `config` in our original code is presumably out of scope. I'm not confused as to why this didn't work when we deployed it, but I *am* confused as to why it worked locally. Either way, the fix above works well in both, so the issue is resolved.